# Book about Glorious Revolution

Tags: england, 17th-century, industrial-revolution

I am currently reading Acemoglu, Daron & Robinson, James: *Why Nations Fail*, which made me want to read more about the Glorious Revolution of 1688. I am particularly interested in an economic perspective and works looking at how inventions helped drive economic growth and eventually lead to the industrial revolution. Is there any good book that deals with this particular angle that you would recommend?

Comment: Questions that are purely requests for off-site sources are usually considered off-topic here. Perhaps you can rephrase the question (or even ask multiple questions) so that it can be answered in SE format (i.e. in a few paragraphs). A good answer will include references to the source documents and books.

Comment: @SteveBird I suspected as much. Unfortunately any question I might be interested in asking would be too broad, hence the desire to find a good source so that I can read it myself. I guess I will have to google and read reviews at goodreads and amazon instead to find a suitable book. Thanks though!

Comment: Actually a work of fiction, [Neal Stephenson's Baroque Cycle](http://www.nealstephenson.com/baroque-cycle/), covers this a bit. The 3 tomes are about a jillion pages total, but a great read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a hard request to fulfill. The interesting economic stuff happened later, so there aren't too many books covering what you're looking for.

Arnold Toynbee is your best bet.

http://socserv2.socsci.mcmaster.ca/~econ/ugcm/3ll3/toynbee/indrev

After that, I recommend Eric Hobsbawm.

- The Age of Revolution: Europe 1789-1848
- The Age of Capital: 1848-1875
- The Age of Empire: 1875-1914